# Does running a bash script as root change the ownership of files to root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, root, ownership

I know I should just test one of my scripts on a file after making a backup copy, but I'd like to know if it will make any difference, as I have several scripts that perform identical tasks on multiple files. And today I was tempted to run one or two as root. Instead I "erred on the side of caution" and came here.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the script, but usually, if you run a script with sudo (as root), everything created or modified will get owned by root. This can create problems, if you are running GUI application programs, which often have configuration files in your home directory, In these cases you should use `sudo -H gui-program` for example `sudo -H gedit`, but it is recommended to use a text mode editor, for example `sudo nano` when you need elevated permissions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If a file is read, no ownership is changed. If however a file is created it will have 'root' as owner,  if the file is added-to the ownership should not change (eg. a `sudo cat >>file` will not change the ownership of 'file')

Answer (score 3):

Where you haven't said what the script does, it's impossible to say exactly, but here's a quick breakdown of different file operations:

- **Reading/writing an existing file**: no, the file will not change ownership

  - e.g. `cat`/`tee`
- **Creating a new file**: yes, new files will be owned by root

  - e.g. `touch`
- **Changing file ownership**: yes, of course

  - e.g. `chown root`
- **Changing file permissions**: no

  - e.g. `chmod`

Comment: the script is written to modify an image file using a command line executable. I'd hate to see a file's ownership change from my username to root when I didn't mean for it to be changed by the script.